# Crazy talk (paranoid about initialization)

Tags: c++

I learned long ago that the only reliable way for a static member of be initialized for sure is to do in a function. Now, what I'm about to do is to start returning static data by non-const reference and I need someone to stop me.

```
function int& dataSlot()
{
    static int dataMember = 0;
    return dataMember;
}
```

To my knowledge this is the only way to ensure that the static member is initlized to zero. However, it creates obscure code like this:

```
dataSlot() = 7; // perfectly normal?
```

The other way is to put the definition in a translation unit and keep the stuff out of the header file. I have nothing against that per se but I have no idea what the standard says regard when and under what circumstances that is safe.

The absolute last thing I wanna end up doing is accidently accessing uninitialized data and losing control of my program.

Comment: Why do you need to return a non-const reference?

Comment: @Andrey I have a single use case where I actually want to be able to modify a static value but I also want it to have a specific default value.

Comment: Code like `dataSlot()=7` is perfectly normal, then.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that this question goes over your head @Mankarse

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: I don't see any question mark, and I don't feel that `dataSlot() = 7` is obscure. I certainly don't think that it is possible to give a definitive factual answer to "I need someone to stop me".

Comment: Right. I have several answers already though. So there's some creativity obviously involved here. All I need is facts and alternatives about initialization of static members. Got any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning a non-const reference in itself is fairly harmless, for example it's what `vector::at()` does, or `vector::iterator::operator*`.

If you don't like the syntax `dataSlot() = 7;`, you could define:

```
void setglobal(int i) {
    dataSlot() = i;
}
int getglobal() {
    return dataSlot();
}
```

Or you could define:

```
int *dataSlot() {
    static int dataMember = 0;
    return &dataMember;
}

*dataSlot() = 7; // better than dataSlot() = 7?
std::cout << *dataSlot(); // worse than std::cout << dataSlot()?
```

If you want someone to stop you, they need more information in order to propose an alternative to your use of mutable global state!

Comment: I did consider just hiding the fact that it's returned as non-const reference like that but I thought I could get way by simply defining this in translation unit but I'm not sure about the initialization order.

Comment: If I have a cpp file with `int MyClass::dataSlot = 0` is there anyway I could potentially access dataSlot and it wasn't zero?

Comment: Only if you modified it to some other value.

Answer (score 6):

(With the usual cautions against indiscriminate use of globals...) Just declare the variable at global scope. It is guaranteed to be zero-initialized before any code runs.

You have to be more cunning when it comes to types with non-trivial constructors, but ints will work fine as globals.

Comment: The difference to global variable is that the single instance is created when the function called, so the functionality is not the same (specially when an exception can be thrown from the constructor).

Comment: @BЈовић: `int`'s “constructor” doesn't throw.

Comment: ok, right. I was thinking of a more general case (how this thing is really used)

Comment: Okay, I'll check that, I'm only dealing with primitive types (and a pointer) so this might work just fine. I was hoping to just keep it really simple.

Comment: Is there a difference between global variables and static member variables?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: No, global variables and static member variables are the same thing except for the later you can (mostly) prevent unrelated code from accessing them.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Meyers singletor](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/), and it is almost perfectly safe.

You have to take care that the object is  created when the function dataSlot() is called, but it is going to be destroyed when the program exists (somewhere when global variables are destructed), therefore you have to take special care. Using this function in destructors is specially dangerous and might cause random crashes.

Comment: Almost correct. To the point I am considering a downvote (not downvoting because the link is good). The object is constructed when the function is first called. The runtime ensures that, you don't have to take care of anything. It is destroyed during global destruction, in the reverse order of constructor completions. The runtime takes care of that (unless the application is killed or terminate()s), usually by registering destructor via underlying C library's atexit.

Comment: It's not "perfectly safe": it could be destroyed before other static objects, which could then try to access it from their destructors. In this case that will probably go unnoticed since it has a trivial destructor; but more generally that can lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mike: order of destruction is reverse order of completion of constructors, isn't it? So the correct thing to do if you want your object to refer to this thing in its destructor, is to also refer to it in its constructor, thus ensuring that the global is constructed before your object and hence destroyed after. It's a while since I needed this kind of thing, though, I sort of agree that the fact I'm unsure means it can't really be called "perfectly" safe.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I suppose you could do that; but it's error-prone, and therefore still not "perfectly safe".

Comment: Oh, and I should have mentioned that if my object that's going to refer to it in its destructor has dynamic lifetime, then referring in the constructor doesn't help. This has more opportunity for error than many things in C++. "Safe" is relative anyway: if "opportunity for error" implies "not perfectly safe", then the perfectly safe subset of C++ is probably empty ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I learned long ago that the only reliable way for a static member of be initialized for sure is to do in a function.

No, it isn't. The standard guarantees that:

1. All objects with static storage (both block and file or class-static scope) **with trivial constructors** are initialized before any code runs. Any code of the program at all.
2. All objects with file/global/class-static scope and non-trivial constructos are than initialized before the `main` function is called. It is guaranteed that if objects A and B are defined in the same translation unit and A is defined before B, than A is initialized before B. However order of construction of objects defined in different translation units is unspecified and will often differ between compilations.
3. Any block-static objects are initialized when their declaration is reached for the first time. Since C++03 standard does not have any support for threads, [**this is NOT thread-safe!**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx)
4. All objects with static storage (both block and file/global/class-static scoped) are destroyed in the reverse order of their constructors *completing* after the `main()` function exits or the application terminates using `exit()` system call.

Neither of the methods is usable and reliable in all cases!

> Now, what I'm about to do is to start returning static data by non-const reference and I need someone to stop me.

Nobody is going to stop you. It's legal and perfectly reasonable thing to do. But make sure you don't fall in the threads trap.

E.g. any reasonable unit-test library for C++ automatically registers all test cases. It does it by having something like:

```
std::vector<TestCase *> &testCaseList() {
    static std::vector<TestCase *> test_cases;
    return test_cases;
}

TestCase::TestCase() {
    ...
    testCaseList().push_back(this);
}
```

Because that's the one of only two ways to do it. The other is:

```
TestCase *firstTest = NULL;

class TestCase {
    ...
    TestCase *nextTest;
}

TestCase::TestCase() {
    ...
    nextTest = firstTest;
    firstTest = this;
}
```

this time using the fact that `firstTest` has trivial constructor and therefore *will* be initialized before any of the `TestCase`s that have non-trivial one.

> dataSlot() = 7; // perfectly normal?

Yes. But if you really want, you can do either:

1. The old C thing of

   ```
   #define dataSlot _dataSlot()
   ```

   in a way the `errno` "variable" is usually defined,
2. Or you can wrap it in a struct like

   ```
   class dataSlot {
       Type &getSlot() {
           static Type slot;
           return slot;
       }
       operator const Type &() { return getSlot(); }
       operator=(Type &newValue) { getSlot() = newValue; }
   };
   ```

   (the disadvantage here is that compiler won't look for Type's method if you try to invoke them on dataSlot directly; that's why it needs the operator=)

Answer (score 0):

You could make yourself 2 functions, dataslot() and set_dataslot() which are wrappers round the actual dataslot, a bit like this:

```
int &_dataslot() { static int val = 0; return val; }
int dataslot() { return _dataslot(); }
void set_dataslot(int n) { _dataslot() = n; }
```

You probably wouldn't want to inline that lot in a header, but I've found some C++ implementations do rather badly if you try that sort of thing anyway.